# How would I return a user to previous URL with errors and appending an anchor tag?

Tags: php, laravel-5

This code does everything I need

```
return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->errors());
```

Accept append a anchor tag i.e. (www.examplewebsite.com/home#anchor).

This code does everything I need

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#contact");
```

Accept pass the errors from my Validator.

Here is the code in its entirety for context

```
public function contact(Request $request) {

    $input = $request->input();
    $email = $input['email'];
    $name = $input['name'];

    $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'text' => $input['text']
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'required|min:5',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'text' => 'required|min:5'
        )
    );

    if($validator->fails()) {

        return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->errors());

    } else {

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $input, function($message) use ($email, $name) {
            $message->from('auto@email.com', 'Auto');
            $message->to('example@email.com', 'Mong Goose')->subject('A Contact Form');
        });

        return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#contact");
    }
}
```

How can achieve the following in one redirect:

- send user to previous URL
- append an anchor to previous URL
- send errors

Comment: You question is quite confusing. Where would you return the user? After it detects validation error or not?

Comment: To the previous page.

In this case a page containing a Form which would send a POST request to this Method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using redirect back?

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error', 'Error Message']);
```

To get the error message, you can use:

```
Session::has('error')
```

blade template

```
@if (count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks. But when redirecting the user back, how would I append an anchor?

Comment: you can use your `return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#anchor");` @Mongo0se